# how i want to read text in text file using scanner and ignoring the unavailable value

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

[image: Screenshot]
I was implementing a toll management system.

| userIC | startPoint | endPoint | vehicleClass | vehicle reg no | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |

This is my text file. I use it like a database. Actually, I just want to do a checkup whether a `userIC` exists or not. If yes, the database should be updated to

| userIC | startPoint | endPoint | vehicleClass | vehicle reg no | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123123123 | Terengganu |  | 1 | S1231 | Progress |

The database should be like this, because if the data does not exist, then it creates new user trip details and if it exists, I want to skip reading the endpoint. Because if only `startPoint` exists, its means the user still not completed the trip and they will go to the `endPoint` to exit toll. At the `endPoint`, the text file should become like this.

| userIC | startPoint | endPoint | vehicleClass | vehicle reg no | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123123123 | Terengganu | kuantan | 1 | S1231 | Paid |

```java
    public void callToCheck(String boothBranch) throws FileNotFoundException{
        long[] utdIC = new long[100];
        int[] utdvehicleClass = new int[100];
        String[] utdvehicleRegNo = new String[100];
        String[] utdstartPoint = new String[100];
        String[] utdendPoint = new String[100];
        String[] utdstatus = new String[100];
        File f = new File("UserTripDetail.txt");
        Scanner readFile = new Scanner(f);
        skipLines(readFile, 1);

        int j = 0;
        while (readFile.hasNext()){
            j++;
            utdIC[j] = readFile.nextLong();
            utdstartPoint[j] = readFile.next();
            utdendPoint[j] = readFile.next();
            utdvehicleClass[j] = readFile.nextInt();
            utdvehicleRegNo[j] = readFile.next();
            utdstatus[j] = readFile.next();

            //checkExistUTD(userIC,status,boothBranch);
        }
```

Keep displaying error.
When I do it differently, it shows `NoSuchElement`.
Now it's displaying this error.

```java
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
        at MainSystem.UserTripDetail.callToCheck(UserTripDetail.java:45)
        at MainSystem.MainSystem.main(MainSystem.java:40)
    C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
    BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)
```

Comment: which line is this? UserTripDetail.java:45

Comment: Unrelated, yet important: you should really study [classes and objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html). Java is an object-oriented language, and you are using a bunch of separate arrays to hold your data. You should instead create a `UserTripDetail` class with `userIc`, `startPoint`, et cetera, as fields. You can then create a `UserTripDetail` array.

Comment: utdvehicleClass[j] = readFile.nextInt(); this is line 45

Comment: have you debugged your code? Have you checked that there is a value to read? Have you checked that it is an int?

Comment: theres no value on endpoint. and i want to skip reading on variable thats no value

Comment: can somebody help me ? :(.. im really stuck..